# Amend collation of results depending on language selected

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that contains 60000+ records of words in 15 different languages.

When running a select statement for a particular language, is there a way to set the correct collation for the selected language?

I know that I can set the collation in the `order by` clause, can this be done on the fly?

So could I do something like this:

```
DECLARE @Language VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @Collation VARCHAR(50)
SET @Language = 'Czech'
SET @Collation = 'Czech_CI_AS'

SELECT Words FROM TABLE1 
WHERE Language = @Language
ORDER BY Words COLLATE @Collation
```

Comment: I think you will need to use a dynamic query

Comment: I would create  a view for each language.

Comment: I had wondered about that myself, but just interested to know if there was another way rather than creating numerous views